# Compiling actionscript via actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, air, mxmlc

I'm in the process of creating a tool which needs to be able to compile a swf file. The interface preferably has to be flash/air.

I have a rough idea about how it could be done but there is some holes...

My thoughts go something like this:

1. Write a file with the actionscript class(Fairly straighforward with air I believe)
2. Compile the file via the mxml compiler(http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withmxmlc/)

Whats the best way to automate the compiling so it's called via actionscript? Please point me in a good direction and you'd have my undying gratitude.
Many thanks.

Comment: Check this 2 links : http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/index.html , http://eval.hurlant.com/demo/#app=da4a&757d-selectedIndex=0 , it may help You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at this actionscript editor build with AIR.
http://code.google.com/p/minibuilder/

The same guy created an online version using a compiler build with java:
http://www.victordramba.com/?p=34

I guess this is not exactly what you want, but just noticing it; create/alter SWF files on the fly:
https://github.com/claus/as3swf

Comment: Thanks. Didn't have time to get my hands dirty yet but these look really useful at first glance. I'd actually seen minibuilder a long time ago but forgot all about it.